# What is Akka doing when nothing happens?

Tags: akka

I have very simple application (2 actors) that sends file through socket. Application uses Spring Boot and Akka, and after transfer is finished, nothing else happens. However, I have noticed high CPU usage, even after transfer (like 50% on 4 core machine, so full 2 cores). I have captured snapshot of active threads, and about 1/3 of them belongs to Akka.

What is Akka doing, and why does it take so much cpu?

http://pastebin.com/CF9yUvuL

Comment: post your code please

Comment: Note though that all those threads are `WAITING` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.State.html), so that they are taking 50% of your CPU is likely an incorrect conclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question generally: Akka creates a thread pool which is used to do asynchronous message processing. So if you write code like the following, your application would never terminate since Akka keeps on running.

```
class Root extends Actor {

  // create some child actors to do some work

  override def receive: Receive = Actor.emptyBehavior
}

object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val system = ActorSystem("main")
    system.actorOf(Props(new Root))
  }
}
```

So usually if you need to terminate your application you would define a message which signals that all work has been done and send this message to your root actor. The root actor can then call `context.system.terminate()` to terminate the system.

Coming back to your question, I don't understand why you would want to combine Akka with Spring Boot. Your thread dump, I'm not sure whether the problem is related to Akka at all. It looks like the threads are hanging inside HttpClient. Are you sure you have freed and closed all open connections?

Comment: I have no problem with creating multiple threads, I just do not understand, why are those threads still active (instead of waiting for message). Application is server, so it intentionally isn't terminated. I don't see a reason, why Akka + Spring would be bad idea, they do different things. There was only one connection over socket, that successfully completed.

Comment: Discussing Akka + Spring Boot is probably out of scope of this question. Sorry for that. It's pretty hard to find out what's going on without some code samples. Can you add an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to your question?